# How to solve the A Syntax Error Occurred in mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have fetching some data from database when ever i run the query showing Error but I'm not found the issue please check it my code and guide me what issue I did my code..thanks

**Issue NOTE: A Database Error Occurred : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND `isArchived` is NULL' at line 3**

my query:

```
$validGrades =   $this->db->select('id,name')
                 ->where_in('id', $gradesIds)
                 ->where('isArchived is NULL')
                 ->get('grades')
                 ->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

its a **codeigniter** query, you need to use `NULL , False` as below

```
$validGrades =   $this->db->select('id,name')
                          ->where_in('id', $gradesIds)
                          ->where('isArchived is NULL', NULL, FALSE)
                          ->get('grades')
                          ->result_array();
```

Comment: Hi Devsi,,again showing like that : <div id="container">
  <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
  <p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
AND isArchived is NULL' at line 3</p><p>SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `grades`
WHERE `id` IN()
AND isArchived is NULL</p><p>Filename: models/menugrades/Info_model.php</p><p>Line Number: 80</p> </div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

as you're using wrong syntex. here's the correction

***TRY FOLLOWING CODE***

```
$validGrades = $this->db->select('id,name')
    ->from('grades')
    ->where_in('id', $gradesIds)
    ->where('isArchived is NULL')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```